# I'm getting the `Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>`

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, addeventlistener

can anybody help

I have a list of item where when I click on each name, I wanted to show the data of the item that is being clicked.

But I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>`

If I apply `forEach` for the `data` inside the `n.addEventListener('click'...`, it works fine, but it will show all the `data` for all list, not only the one where I clicked.

This is the code:

```js
const name = document.querySelectorAll('.name')
const data = document.querySelectorAll('.data')

name.forEach(n => {
  n.addEventListener('click', () => {
    data.classList.toggle('show')
  })
})
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="name">
    <h3>Jack</h3>
    <div class="data">
      <span>Age: 18</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="name">
    <h3>Mike</h3>
    <div class="data">
      <span>Age: 19</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="name">
    <h3>Greg</h3>
    <div class="data">
      <span>Age: 17</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `querySelectorAll` which returns multiple elements, and then attempting to use `classList` which is a property of a single element. You need to iterate through each `.data` element as well and call `classList` on that:

```
name.forEach(n => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        n.addEventListener('click', () => {
            d.classList.toggle('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Unless you want all `.data` elements to toggle their `show` on the click, in which case you'd reverse the nesting of the functions:

```
name.forEach(n => {
    n.addEventListener('click', () => {
        data.forEach(d => {
            d.classList.toggle('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it toggles all the `.data`, which I dont want it like that. As for the first one, I tried it too and the outcome is the same as the second one

Comment: That solution seems to be what you were trying to implement - what behaviour do you actually want in the program?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution below. You need to take care of performance as well. Binding event on each `<li>` is not a good approach. We can utilize event delegation concept here.

```
document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('name')) {
        target.querySelector('.data').classList.toggle('show');
        return;
    }
    
    if(target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h3'){
    const parentLi = target.closest('li')
    parentLi.querySelector('.data').classList.toggle('show');
    }
})
```

Comment: To preserve the performance advantage given by event delegation, it's also good to avoid DOM traversing in the event handler. You can do this by [relying on the existing markup](https://jsfiddle.net/74wbf2pm/).